# With PyQt, what is the preferred (efficient) method for monitoring window size and adjusting layouts?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a grid of items in PyQt, and when the user modifies the window size I need to increase/decrease the number of columns accordingly. The number of rows are handled by a scrollarea, so I don't need to worry about changes in the y direction (if that matters).

Inside my implementation of QMainWindow, I know it's possible to override the resizeEvent() function, which will be triggered for any and all window adjustments. However, using that to rebuild the grid everytime is horribly inefficient. Just to test the function to see how it worked, I had resizeEvent merely print a string, and that caused my window adjustments to be slightly laggy and visually imperfect (jittery rather than smooth). I'll probably run a simple division operation on the window size to see if it has gotten larger or smaller enough to change the number of columns, but even that, when run a hundred times per adjustment, might cause lag issues. Rebuilding the entire grid might even take a second to do, so it would be preferable not to need to do it as the user is manipulating the window.

Is there a more efficient way to do it, or is resizeEvent my only option? Ideally, I'd like an event that triggered only once the user finished adjusting the window and not an event that triggers for practically every pixel movement as they happen (which can be hundreds or thousands of times per adjustment in the span of 1 second).

I'm using PyQt5, but if you're more familiar with PyQt4, I can figure out your PyQt4 solution in the context of PyQt5. Same for a C++ Qt4/5 solution.

Comment: Very interested in this as well as I implemented something like this myself by overriding the resizeEvent, and yes it is a bit laggy. It's not very good code (written when I first starting programming in PySide), but might be useful as a benchmark for someone trying to implement something better. Code is here: https://bitbucket.org/labscript_suite/labscript_utils/src/8d38d7f3b72b1f66a5383eaec152788ce6b4e432/qtwidgets/toolpalette.py?at=default

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the only real problem is detecting when resizing has completed. So long as this is carefully controlled, the actual laying out can be done in any way you like.

Below is a solution that uses a timer to control when a resize-completed signal is emitted. It doesn't appear to be laggy, but I haven't tested it with any complex layouts (should be okay, though).

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    resizeCompleted = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self._resize_timer = None
        self.resizeCompleted.connect(self.handleResizeCompleted)

    def updateResizeTimer(self, interval=None):
        if self._resize_timer is not None:
            self.killTimer(self._resize_timer)
        if interval is not None:
            self._resize_timer = self.startTimer(interval)
        else:
            self._resize_timer = None

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.updateResizeTimer(300)

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if event.timerId() == self._resize_timer:
            self.updateResizeTimer()
            self.resizeCompleted.emit()

    def handleResizeCompleted(self):
        print('resize complete')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I would be interested in the `handleResizeCompleted` method if you are still around. The thing I tried is calculating a factor (current window size / initial window size) that will then multiply `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` or all my widgets, as well as their font size probably. The problem is finding the window size. Any idea about that? :)

Comment: None of what I tried/read today worked. `self.window().size()` is constant when I resize my window, just like `self.size()` and `self.geometry()`.

Comment: @Guimoute Please start a new question and provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `FlowLayout`fot this purpose, which automatically adjusts the number of columns on resizing the widget containing it. [Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-flowlayout.html) is the documentation for `FlowLayout` and [here](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py) is the PyQt version of the same layout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately however, it seems that FlowLayout was removed in PyQt5. Attempted to use it got me an attribute error, so I checked the documentation and it is nowhere to be found. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/class_reference.html